# List of version strings - find all versions in a given version area

Tags: powershell

I have a list of strings with version number:

```
1.1.1.0001
1.1.1.0002
1.1.2.0003
1.1.3.0004
1.2.1.0005
1.2.2.0006
2.1.1.0007
2.2.1.0008
```

I want to find out which version numbers are in a specified version area.
E.g. All versions in this area: 1.1.3.0004 - 2.1.1.0007.

Expected Result:

```
1.1.3.0004
1.2.1.0005
1.2.2.0006
2.1.1.0007
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you can just use the `Version` class. Cast each string to `Version` and compare:

```
PS Home:\> $versions = -split '1.1.1.0001
>>> 1.1.1.0002
>>> 1.1.2.0003
>>> 1.1.3.0004
>>> 1.2.1.0005
>>> 1.2.2.0006
>>> 2.1.1.0007
>>> 2.2.1.0008'

PS Home:\> $versions | where { [version]$_ -ge '1.1.3.0004' -and [version]$_ -le '2.1.1.7' }
1.1.3.0004
1.2.1.0005
1.2.2.0006
2.1.1.0007
```

Note that the comparison will automatically convert the right operand to `Version` if the left operand is.

Comment: Thanks that´s a very nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the strings to a 'version' and perform the respective check

```
$Min = [version]::new('1.1.3.0004')
$Max = [version]::new('2.1.1.0007')
'1.1.1.0001','1.1.1.0002','1.1.2.0003','1.1.3.0004','1.2.1.0005','1.2.2.0006','2.1.1.0007','2.2.1.0008' | Where-Object {
   [version]::new($_) -le $Max -and
   [version]$_ -ge $Min
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you use the Version ctor explicitly in all but one case?